# How to Split a Folder into sub-folder in bash script

Tags: linux, files, scripting, mv

I have one Folder receiving *.DAT file continuously every seconds. I want to split that folder into two folder where the parent(Folder which i want to split into two) folder will move all *.DAT file it receives in those two sub-folder in round robin fashion. Is there any way to do this by bash scripting?

Comment: A script containing a loop that process new files in the directory?

Comment: *continuously every seconds* - if content  written into a file comes in the continuous manner, you will break a file integrity when starting to move that file in some time point of the writing process. You should set "round-robin" logic at the side/process which is initiating `*.DAT` files creation, no need to split the final folder

Comment: If a file is moved on the *same filesystem* during writing, data integrity is preserved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# enter the source dir
cd /tmp/a

# set initial subdir
subdir="b"

# run forever
while true
do
        # get first available *.DAT file
        newfile=`ls -1 *.DAT 2>/dev/null | head -n1`
        if [ "$newfile" != "" ]
        then
                # if the .DAT file exists, move it
                mv ./$newfile /tmp/$subdir/

                # replace subdir for next loop iteration
                if [ "$subdir" == "b" ]
                then
                        subdir="c"
                else
                        subdir="b"
                fi
        else
                # nothing found, wait 1 second
                sleep 1
        fi
done
```

I've used flat structure for testing

```
/tmp/a # source dir
/tmp/b # destdir 1
/tmp/c # destdir 2
```

You'll have to modify it to your situation, but it should work.

Comment: Amazingly worked. sorry for late reply which i for some reason missed. thanks again